# VBA color row with specific value/string upto the last column

Tags: excel, vba, colors, row

I would like to color rows with specific cell values (string) in a data set.
I have come across the following code which works perfectly with "entire row" but I would like to color the row only up to the last column which contains some value (and there are spaces in between).
I have tried to specify the last column and use it with Range to color, but it does not go well with vCell...
Thank you for the help!

```
Sub Highlight()

    Dim vCell As Range
    'Loop through every used cell in the active worksheet
    For Each vCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If InStr(vCell.Value, "anyword") Then
            vCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            vCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 255, 204)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below modified sub.

```
Sub Highlight()
Dim vCell As Range
Dim lastCol As Long
    'Loop through every used cell in the active worksheet
    For Each vCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If InStr(vCell.Value, "anyword") Then
            vCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            lastCol = Cells(vCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Range(Cells(vCell.Row, vCell.Column), Cells(vCell.Row, lastCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 255, 204)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: you beat me to it :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly. Learn a new expression, too!

Comment: @Makiko Then please accept the answer so that visitor can know it solved.

Comment: sorry I didn't know the system... thank you for letting me know that!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Highlight()
    Dim vCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Loop through every used cell in the active worksheet
        For Each vCell In .UsedRange
            If InStr(vCell.Value, "anyword") Then
                vCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                
                '~~> Find last column in that row
                lCol = .Cells(vCell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
                .Range(.Cells(vCell.Row, 1), .Cells(vCell.Row, lCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 255, 204)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I like your approach use of `With` block which is faster. In this case `ActiveSheet` will be more effective so that OP can use code to any sheet without changing sheet name.

Comment: Activesheet should be avoided as much as possible :) But then that is just my opinion...

Comment: You are correct. I also agreed not to use `Activesheet`.

Comment: @Makiko: Did you change `Set ws = Sheet1` to relevant sheet?

Comment: Thank you so much! This also worked perfectly. Learn a new expression, too!